# Proving an identity related to inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I recently began working on some problems related to inner product spaces in
linear algebra, and I ran into one that seems somewhat extensive that I could
use some help on. Consider $v_1,...,v_n$ to be an orthonormal basis for
inner product space $V$. I want to prove that for any $x,y \in V$,
$$\langle x,y \rangle  = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,v_k \rangle \overline{\langle y,v_k\rangle },$$

where $\overline{\langle a,b \rangle }$ represents the conjugate of the inner product $\langle a,b \rangle.$

My friend recommended that I should recognize that
$$x = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i$$
where
$$\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \in \mathbb{C}$$
$$y = \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i v_i$$
where
$$\beta_1,...,\beta_n \in \mathbb{C}.$$

I can see that
$$\langle x,y \rangle  = \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i, \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i v_i \right\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \bar{\beta}_i \langle v_i,v_i \rangle  = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i
\bar{\beta}_i.$$

Hence, This really comes down to showing that $\alpha_i = \langle x,v_i \rangle  \wedge \bar{\beta}_i = \overline{\langle  y,v_i \rangle}.$ However, I am having some difficulties
showing this step. Any recommendation on how to best argue the previous
statements?

Comment: Note that you can escape the angular brackets correctly by using the `\langle` ($\langle$) and `\rangle` ($\rangle$) commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the other way round:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,v_k\rangle \overline{\langle y,v_k\rangle}= & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \bigg\langle \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iv_i,v_k\bigg\rangle \overline{\bigg\langle \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_iv_i,v_k\bigg\rangle} \\
 &= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n  \Bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\langle v_i,v_k\rangle\Bigg) \Bigg(\overline{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i\langle v_i,v_k\rangle}\Bigg)\\
& = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \overline{\beta_k}\\
& = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \overline{\beta_k} \langle v_k,v_k\rangle\\
& = \bigg\langle \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_kv_k, \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_iv_i \bigg\rangle\\
& = \langle x,y\rangle 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$